# Aggregating over subsets of columns in Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to compute the aggregate metrics (e.g. mean, median, sum) of column subsets in a numpy array.

Take this array for example:

```
1 6 3 4
2 3 4 5
1 4 5 6
3 5 6 7
```

I have a set of clusters, which are lists of column indices like this:

```py
clusters = [[0, 1], [2], [3]]
```

Both the array and the list of cluster indices can be large and I can guarantee that each column in the array belongs to exactly one cluster, i.e. there are no duplicates in the clusters list. The indexes in the list aren't necessarily ordered, i.e. `[[0, 3], [2, 1]]` would also be a valid cluster.

What I'm looking for is for example summing up the values per cluster - the result for the example above would look like this:

```
[25, 18, 22]
```

A simple implementation in python could look like this:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [1, 6, 3, 4],
    [2, 3, 4, 5],
    [1, 4, 5, 6],
    [3, 5, 6, 7],
])

clusters = [[0, 1], [2], [3]]

result = np.array([arr[:,c_indices].sum() for c_indices in clusters])
# array([25, 18, 22])
```

My problem is that the matrix and number of clusters can grow quite large and I'd like to avoid looping in Python and instead keeping as much of this as possible in numpy's C-implementation for performance reasons.

**Are there more efficient ways of doing this?**
(Ideally compatible with min, max, median, mean, and sum)

Comment: Are the clusters always in order?

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but `clusters` could also be `[[0, 3], [2, 1]]` if that helps, I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A start would be to sum the columns in numpy and then only sum up the results:

```
n = 10**4
arr = np.random.rand(n,n)
clusters = [[random.randint(0,n-1) for _ in range(random.randint(0,n))] 
             for _ in range(n//100)]
```

```
%%timeit 
arr_sumed = arr.sum(0)
[arr_sumed[c_indices].sum() for c_indices in clusters]
```

38.6 ms ± 1.08 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit [arr[:,c_indices].sum() for c_indices in clusters]
```

27.3 s ± 382 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

### What if I want a median instead of a sum?

Ok I hope somebody else will come up with a better solution BUT one thing you can do is sort the columns in advance. Then you can find the index of a number with adding up the indices in the sorted lists. Finally you do binary search for the median:

```
n = 10**4
arr = np.random.rand(n,n)
clusters = [np.array([random.randint(0,n-1) for i in range(random.randint(0,n))]) for j in range(n//100)]
```

```
%%time
def median_from_sorted_arrays(arr_sorted, arr_min, arr_max, c_indices):
    n = len(arr_min)*len(c_indices)
    a = min(arr_min[c_indices])
    b = max(arr_max[c_indices])

    while True:
        k = sum(np.searchsorted(arr_sorted[i], (a+b)/2) for i in c_indices)
        if k/n < 0.499:
            a = (a+b)/2
        elif k/n > 0.501:
            b = (a+b)/2    
        else:
            return (a+b)/2

arr_sorted = np.sort(arr, 0)
arr_min = np.min(arr, 0)
arr_max = np.max(arr, 0)

[median_from_sorted_arrays(arr_sorted, arr_min, arr_max,c_indices) for c_indices in clusters]
```

This took 13.7 seconds compared to 1min 43s for the naive approach.

Note that though the binary search should always work and give a perfect solution I didn't take the time to work out the correct stopping criterion making this median an approximation.

Comment: Uh, I didn't think of that, this should work for sum, min, and max :-) - Any idea how to optimize median and mean?

Comment: @Maurice Mean should also just work and I added an non perfect approach for the median (fixed a typo)